# MySQL - Replacing first space with characters

Tags: mysql

I have a column 'full_name' in a table of users. Seeing as I don't want to change the table structure, I am looking for a way to replace the first space in each name with two characters (%$ for instance), so that my code will know where to split the first and second name.

This will make future name entries work even if the given name is a double name.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Could this be achieved in your code by splitting at the first space?

Comment: Why are you against changing the table structure?

Comment: The table is in the core of the CMS I'm using. I assume changing the table structure may cause some unexpected results.

Comment: By adding special characters to the value, you'll also have "unexpected results". Both solutions will require refactoring of existing code. It seems to me that if you'll have to refactor anyway, choosing the path of more normalized data structures is the right way to go.

Comment: Noted. Thanks Sonny!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, the best thing might be to redesign your schema to have separate columns for the first and last names.  If you cannot do this and you need a query to extract out the first and last names, then consider the following queries.  I don't think you need to add a special delimeter.  Rather, you can just use standard MySQL string functions.

Here is a query you can use to extract the first name (everything up until the first space):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(full_name, 1, INSTR(full_name, ' ')-1)
```

Here is a query for the remainder:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(full_name,
                 INSTR(full_name, ' ') + 1,
                 CHAR_LENGTH(full_name) - INSTR(full_name, ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a conversion script in PHP or whatever language you're using in your stack. You would execute it right before deploying the new code that uses your specified format.